# When I return json data to front end it shows empty list

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am retrieving list of address from the database which I want to display in front end as autocomplete list.
When I type letter on search field it shows empty field.
while I can print json data on console.
It would be very nice if get some code snippet.

**Here is my controller**

```
package com.searching.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.searching.model.Address;
import com.searching.service.SearchService;

@Controller
public class SearchingController {

    @Autowired SearchService searchService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchPage() {
        //runthismethod();
        return "testpage";
    }


    @GetMapping("/addressAutocomplete")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSearchdata(@RequestParam(value="term",defaultValue="",required=false) String term) {
        List<Address> address=searchService.fetchAddress();
        Gson json=new Gson();

        String response=json.toJson(address);

        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**front end**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/addressAutocomplete",
                 autoFocus:true,
                minLength: 2,
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div class = "ui-widget">
         <p>Type "a" or "s"</p>
         <label for = "automplete-1">Tags: </label>
         <input id = "automplete-1">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**json data on console**

[image]

Comment: Can you please try using below code:

 public ResponseEntity<String > getSearchdata(@RequestParam(value="term",defaultValue="",required=false) String term) {

and return

 return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Just do one change in your controller as follows,

```
    @GetMapping("/addressAutocomplete")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Address> getSearchdata(@RequestParam(value="term",defaultValue="",required=false) String term) {
        return searchService.fetchAddress();
    }
```

Spring transforms returned data into JSON.

Comment: Can you check the network tab in chrome for output, if op showing over there means some logic is missing in the angular code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@Controller` annotation so you should send response as response Entity in return type OR just change the `@Controller` annotation to `@RestController`

```
        @GetMapping("/addressAutocomplete")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Address>> getSearchdata (@RequestParam(value = "term", defaultValue = "", required = false) String term){
            List<Address> address = searchService.fetchAddress();
            Gson json = new Gson();

            String response = json.toJson(address);

            System.out.println(response);

            return new ResponseEntity<List<Address>>(address, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

After running your code it gives proper response.

[image]

Comment: did you see my html page... I want to display list there

Comment: I want this list(list of address) to be searched as autocomplete text(i.e. when I search an address it should show suggestions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185039/discussion-between-suraj-kumar-and-raheela-aslam).